# Set size of HTML page and browser window

Tags: html, css, resize, scrollbar

I have a div element with ID="container". I want to set this element to be the size of the viewable area in the browser window. I am using the following JS to do so.

```
var container= document.getElementById("container");
container.style.height=(window.innerHeight);
container.style.width=window.innerWidth;
```

However, the browser window size is larger than the viewable size and horizontal and vertical scroll bars appear. How do I make it so that my HTML page fits into the browser window without a need for scroll bars?

EDIT:

I am basically asking, how can I make the document size the same as the viewport size?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background-color: green;
            }
            #container {
                width: inherit;
                height: inherit;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background-color: pink;
            }
            h1 {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The background colors are there so you can see how this works. Copy this code to a file and open it in your browser. Try playing around with the CSS a bit and see what happens.

The `width: inherit; height: inherit;` pulls the width and height from the parent element. This *should* be the default and is not truly necessary.

Try removing the `h1 { ... }` CSS block and see what happens. You might notice the layout reacts in an odd way. This is because the `h1` element is influencing the layout of its container. You could prevent this by declaring `overflow: hidden;` on the container or the body.

I'd also suggest you do some reading on the [CSS Box Model](http://goo.gl/JBh2j).

Comment: It was a child element of "container" that was giving me issues just like you suggested. good call. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `width: 100%;` in your css.

Comment: tried. still making the document size larger than viewport size.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head >
<title>Welcome</title>    
<style type="text/css">
#maincontainer 
{   
top:0px;
padding-top:0;
margin:auto; position:relative;
width:950px;
height:100%;
}
  </style>
  </head>
<body>
 <div id="maincontainer ">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using meta tags:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content=“width=device-width”>
<title><—-!your title here!—></title>
</head>
<body>
<—-!stuffgoeshere!—->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You could try:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #main {
                width: 500; /*Set to whatever*/
                height: 500;/*Set to whatever*/
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body id="main">
    </body>
</html>
```