# Horizontal Scrolling in UIWebView Not Working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I've looked around for a while and there seems to be quite a few questions on scrolling in UIWebView, but none of the solutions have worked for me. I have a UIWebView inside a view on one of the pages of my app:

```
myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:b];
[myWebView.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1136, 400)];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:styleSheet baseURL:nil];
[myView addSubview:myWebView];
```

Right now, scrolling vertically works fine, but changing `contentSize` seems to not affect anything.

I need to display a small spreadsheet and making the view wider will make it much more readable.

Comment: What's in your stylesheet?

Comment: `styleSheet` is just an `NSString` of HTML code. But changing the content of that variable doesn't really matter to the web view. I've tried it with just `<p>test text</p>` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think you can set the contentSize of your webView's scrollView, it is set by the webView when it loads a webPage or HTML thats higher then the webView itself

Comment: @Refael.S do I need to include some HTML code, then, that will force the content to be the size I want? (Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510359/set-size-of-html-page-and-browser-window)?)

Comment: @MisterMister I posted an answer with details hope that helps you, if the inherit from the example you added in comment does work for you, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the height of the webView page in HTML do this:

```
myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:b];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:styleSheet baseURL:nil];
[myView addSubview:myWebView];
```

where styleSheet is a NSString with this HTML Code:

```
NSString *styleSheet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"html { min-width: 100%%; min-height: 100%%; } body { width: %dpx; height: %dpx; background-color: #FFF; }", myWebView.frame.size.width*2, myWebView.frame.size.height*2];
```

(width*2 and height*2 for retina display)

You can of course add anything you want to the HTML string to change the content of the webView.

Comment: Only change is that the string needs to be enclosed in `<style>` tags.