# html templates with no scrolling needed

Tags: html, css, templates, web

I have to make a static html website for a lcd touch screen to be displayed in a stall in an exhibition. User will give input through touch. I am searching for a static html website that can adapt to any larger resolution like lcds, big leds with no scrolling needed.

I have searched over the internet and have found one page responsive html website templates but scrolling is present in them. I want fix width and height of the template so that there will be no scrolling.

I am not able to find such html website templates. Please help me if anyone has same problem like this.

Thanks
Waqas Joya

Comment: Can you give us atleast an example or what you already have tried your self?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one will help you to set the page width and height.

[Set size of HTML page and browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510359/set-size-of-html-page-and-browser-window)