# How to adapt web content's width and height to window's width and height

Tags: html, css

I would like to set the web content's width and height to fit the windows' width and height.

Currently there are vertical scroll bars both in the cover page and in the scene page.

[image]

The cover image has its own css class coverImage:

```
.coverImage {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In addition the inner scene page has the same behaviour, it shows a vertical scroll bar:
[image]

The images on the left, the thumbnails have its own css class called miniature and the canvas have a class nrrdCanvas:

```
.miniature {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.nrrdCanvas {
    margin: 25px 25px;
}
```

I have also read:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/

[Set size of HTML page and browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510359/set-size-of-html-page-and-browser-window)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use 100vw if u don't want to include scroll bar and overflow hidden?

Answer (score 1):

Without code I can give you general advice. If you want an element on your page to span the full height and width of the window, one way is to set their width and height with viewport units.

```
.element {
   width: 100vw;
   height 100vh;
}
```

But for all the rest of your responsive items just use percentages for the width. Example:

```
.other-element {
   width: 20%;
}
```

Another very useful tool for responsiveness and layout for sections in general is flexbox. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/